# Boot BroadcastReceiver not being called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I'm trying to start an AlarmManager on boot, which in set intervals calls a service that does background updating tasks (data fetched from my server). I read and searched on stackoverflow and I'm still puzzled why it's never getting called. I even added

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

because I'm testing my app on a real HTC Android device.

This is my BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent intent) {
        startAlarmManager(pContext);
        Log.d("Called", "yes");
    }

    void startAlarmManager(Context pContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(pContext);
        String a = readSettings(pContext);
        Integer interval = Integer.parseInt(a);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, interval);

        Intent intent = new Intent(pContext, StudentServisUpdate.class);

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(pContext, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //for 30 mint 60*60*1000
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pintent);
    }

    String readSettings(Context cx) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = cx.openFileInput("settings");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application>
    ...

            </application>

            <!--<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>-->

            <receiver
                android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

        </manifest>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this one? I'm running Android 4.4 and I'm aware for the post 3.1 change.

Comment: Good luck, I was messing around with an app on the side that required a boot receiver. I have an HTC for my personal device and ended up just giving up haha. I am sure that someone has an answer but ~6 months ago I just couldn't get the HTC to recognize boots (HTC DNA).

Comment: "I'm aware for the post 3.1 change" -- your manifest isn't showing an activity. Is there one? Did you run it?

Comment: yeah, there is. I have several activities and one service that I found to be irrelevant to the question and would just clutter the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did a silly mistake. I added my receiver under the application tag, instead within it. Also, it takes a bit longer for the service tp start after booting up, depending on the cellphone performance.